# how to change value of select list on change of another select list in exposed filter

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, drupal-exposed-filter

I have created two exposed filter with the same field District.

When I change the selected value of `District field 1`,  value of list one is set to `District field 2`.

what should I do for achieving this for more clarification of the question I have image attached bellow.

Please see the image:
[image: Please see the image]

Comment: What have you tried already? Have your tried doing a form_alter to manipulate the form (which is how I would do it)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this Drupal module

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters

Comment: is there any configuration for this..
please help me i have installed this module. but nothing happen...

Comment: Tutorial - https://www.lullabot.com/articles/module-monday-views-dependent-filters

Answer (score 0):

Try this module : 
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional

Also this post can helps : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174334/views-conditional-filter